# Is the following a correct prove-method in ZF?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In ZF, let P(x) be some proposition about transitive set $x\neq \emptyset$. And with the assumption $\forall y(y\in x \rightarrow P(y))$ is P(x) provable.
Is it correct to conclude P(x) is true?  The negation of P(x) gives a contradiction so I think P(x) is true, but it seems to me a littlebit tricky.
Thank you for your attention, Doeko Homan

Comment: Do you mean, perhaps, $\forall y(y\in x\rightarrow P(y))$?

Comment: yes, I edit the question

Answer (score 2):

This is known as *Epsilon induction*, and you don't even need $x$ to be transitive. You really just need the axiom of regularity.

> If $P(x)$ is a property such that $\forall x(\forall y(y\in x\rightarrow P(y)))\rightarrow P(x)$, then $\forall x P(x)$.

The proof is nearly trivial if you are familiar with transfinite induction, simply prove this by transfinite induction on the rank of $x$.

Comment: OK, thank you for the reply